# Background Image blocking my whole screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I wanted to add a background `image` to my `UIViewcontroller` in my iOS app.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]     initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width,  self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

This unfortunately produced a result where the whole screen was covered.

Is there a way to move this subview to the bottom layer so that it doesn't cover my `buttons` and `textfields`?

Comment: Please show us the view heirarchy in your storyboard. I assume you are using storyboard

Comment: your imageview bounds are equal to the view bounds,ofcourse it covers the whole screen

Comment: The goal was to add to add just this subview programmatically so that it would automatically adjust the background image to fit the screen.

Comment: sorry , I didnt get you. T means?

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert the view at the bottom of the hierarchy

```
[self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.s and Mr.T for your quick responses!